# Shortcode Inside Class Not Working

Tags: php, shortcode, oop

Working on my first WordPress plugin and using OOP. I'm trying to create a shortcode that works within a class and confused about how to set it up.

With my current setup, the shortcode only prints out the shortcode name on the front end. Here's what I have now inside the class php file:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'month_snapshot' ) ) {

class month_snapshot
{
    private $grand_total;

    public function __construct()
    {
      //code here to create grand_total
      $this->grand_total = $grand_total;
    }

    public function get_grand_total() {
        return $this->grand_total;
    }

    public function display_summary() {
        return "Grand Total is " . $this->grand_total . "<br/>";
    }

    //month_summary shortcode
    public function month_summary_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null) {
        $content = $data->display_summary;          
        return $content;
    }

} //close class

} //close if not exists

//Shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'month_summary', array( 'month_snapshot', 'month_summary_shortcode' ) );
```

---

ETA: Thank you everyone for your help.

I cut out some code on my original post to make it easier to read - probably shouldn't have as it added to some confusion with undeclared variables, etc.

---

RESOLUTION:
For those looking for a similar solution I ended up changing my strategy a bit based on Jess Pinkman's  clarification (thank you).
My class ended up looking like this:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'month_snapshot' ) ) {

class month_snapshot
{
    public $grand_total;

    public function __construct()
    {
      //I omitted code here which got a grand_total, let's pretend it resulted in 1
      $grand_total = 1;
      $this->grand_total = $grand_total;
    }

} //close class

} //close if not exists
```

Then, I declared my shortcode and corresponding function externally. It called upon the class to get the $grand_total result I was looking to display.

```
add_shortcode('month_summary', 'month_summary_shortcode');

function month_summary_shortcode() {
  $month_data = new month_snapshot;
  $monthly_total = "Grand Total is " . $month_data->grand_total . "<br/>";
  return $monthly_total;
}
```

Comment: There are some issues here but it could help if you looked further into static vs instantiated class. Avoid using undefined variables in your methods. What about starting with a class that has only a single (static?) method, make that work, and then expand in smaller steps.

Comment: You're referring to variables that aren't defined or don't exist, such as `$data->display_summary`, and there's no initial value for `$grant_total` either. You will be seeing PHP warnings and notices in your error log for these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use any hooks, filters or shortcodes with class methods, you have three options.

either declare it **in the context of an instance**, in which case, you can refer to the instance of the class.

```php
class myClass {
    function __construct()
    {
        add_shortcode('my_shortcode_name', [ $this, 'shortcode' ]);
    }
    
    function shortcode()
    {
        //your code here
        //properties of the instance are available
        return 'a string';
    }
}
```

or you declare it outside of an instance, then you must use a public static method.

```php
add_shortcode('my_shortcode_name', [myClass::class, 'shortcode']);

class myClass {
    
    
    public static function shortcode()
    {
        //your code here
        //you only have access to static properties
        return 'a string';
    }
    
}
```